# WoocommerceApiClient not working in another FORM

Tags: c#, woocommerce-rest-api

I am using the WoocommerceSharp Woocommerce API tool from zacharykeeton/SharpCommerce.

Link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/putuyoga/WoocommerceSharp)
Its very strange. When i use this code in Program.cs:

```
            var api = new WoocommerceApiClient(StoreUrl, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var _cat = api.Products.Categories.Get().Result;
```

It returns the Categories from my WordPress website and works just fine. When i want to use the same code in another form it does not work and freezes at the var _cat = api.Products.Categories.Get().Result;
 line.

I added this line in my Program.cs line:

```
Application.EnableVisualStyles();
Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
Application.Run(new Form2());
```

When i use this code at the Form load event it just freezes:

> var api = new WoocommerceApiClient(StoreUrl, ConsumerKey, ConsumerSecret);
>   var _cat = api.Products.Categories.Get().Result;
>   var parameters = new Dictionary();

This freezes the call: var _cat = api.Products.Categories.Get().Result;

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same issue. Could you solved it? Tks in advance!